# AWS CDK (Java): Add a Group to a UserPool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

AWS CDK (Java) Attempting to add a Group to UserPool is failing with: "Error: There is already a Construct with name 'CdkStackTest' in Stack [CdkStackTest]". I believe the 'scope' param is creating the CfnUserPoolGroup as another construct with the same name. How do I (correctly) create a group and associate it with a UserPool?

```
public class CdkStackMain extends Stack {

    public CdkStackMain(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props, StackMode stackMode) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // userPool successfully created here

        CfnUserPoolGroup.Builder
                .create(scope, id)
                .groupName("admin")
                .userPoolId(userPool.getUserPoolId())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I replace 'scope' with 'this' and changed 'id' to a unique identifier that the CfnUserPoolGroup could be successfully associated with the UserPool. I also learned that it is best practice to designate that the Group depends on UserPool existence.

```
CfnUserPoolGroup.Builder
    .create(this, "adminGroup")
    .groupName("admin")
    .userPoolId(userPool.getUserPoolId())
    .build()
    .addDependsOn((CfnResource)userPool.getNode().getDefaultChild());
```